# Client Server architecture using python and C#

Tags: c#, python, wcf, client-server, rpc

I am trying an application to write an application on which I have used a client/server architecture. The client side is developed using .NET\C# and the server side is developed on python. To communicate the both sides, I used first tcp/ip socket; so i put my python's methods on a loop then I ask each time from my c# application to run an method. This idea is very bad as it require to cover all use cases that can be happening on network or something like that. After a work of search, I have found three technologies that can answer a client/server architecture which are RPC, RMI and WCF. RMI a java oriented solution so it is rejected. So, my question here is: does RPC and WCF support multi programming languages (interoperability) especially betwenn C# and python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your use case, but I would suggest having a look at a REST API approach if you need to have .Net talk to Python, or vice versa.

Comment: what can a rest API b useful for in my case, comparatively with WCF and RPC?

Comment: Simplicity, really. If your Python app can serve data (JSON/XML) out over HTTP, then your C# client app can consume it. Similarly, your C# app can POST data to the Python API to add/update etc. What you are trying to do may require something more complex than this, but this is where I would start before looking at WCF etc. It's where the world seems to be moving to with microservices etc

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using [Pyro4](https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/) to expose Python objects on your Python server side and talking to them via the C# client library provided by [Pyrolite](https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyrolite.html). This mostly hides any networking specific programming details.